# ОТКУДА - какая часть речи?

Tags: морфология, части-речи

ОТКУДА - какая часть речи в этом тексте: "...дорога уходила туда, откуда даже с городских высот..."
Может быть, союзное слово? Или наречие?..

Comment: нет такой части речи "союзное слово "

Comment: Ну да. Слово есть, а части нету. )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, это наречие. Выступает в роли союзного слова в сложном предложении

Answer (score 5):

Я вижу, надо разъяснить, что такое  союзное слово. Союзное слово--это ФУНКЦИЯ  относительных  местоимений (кто, что,какой, который, чей, сколько) и относительных  местоименных  НАРЕЧИЙ (где, куда, откуда, зачем, как и др.) Поэтому слово "откуда"--это местоименное наречие, являющееся в предложении союзным  словом.В отличие от союзов  такие слова являются  членами предложения.

Comment: Все правильно. Плюс.